# Is there a way to get rid of constness of virtual member functions

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, const-correctness

I need to implement a mock for an interface that is defined something like:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  void sendEvent(int id) const = 0;
}
```

My mock class needs to save all event id's sent to the class. This is how I intended to do it.

```
class FooMock : Foo
{
private: 
  m_vector std::vector<int>;
public:
  void sendEvent(int id) const {m_vector.push_back(id);}

}
```

But obviously the compiler refuses that construction. Are there any solutions to this (assuming the interface could not be changed)?

I realize that I can use two classes for this. But isn't there a way to shut the compiler up and allow me to to this, similar to const_cast?

Comment: mutable turned out to be impossible due to that we work in a model driven environment that doesn't support mutable at all.

Comment: But const_cast<FooMock*>(this)->m_vector.push_back(id); works fine, I was not aware of this possibility. Thanks!

Comment: @Erik: Did `mutable` solve the issue or not? I find it strange that it wouldn't solve it... but your comment says so, and on the other hand you have accepted an answer that proposes the use of `mutable`... If `mutable` did not solve it, why?

Comment: Is the `const` there for a reason? Did the designer put `const` here just because it's prettier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the vector `mutable` so that it can be modified from within const methods, like this:

```
mutable std::vector<int> m_vector;
```

Note however that this makes the vector mutable from *all* methods. If you only want to write to it from a single method, a `const_cast` is less invasive, in that you cast the constness of `this` away just for a single call:

```
FooMock * const that = const_cast<FooMock * const>(this);
that->m_vector.push_back(id);
```

I'm being a bit pedantic here - inside a const method, `this` has the type `T const * const` (so both the object being pointed to as well as the pointer itself are const). The `const_cast` just casts away the constness of the object, but not of the pointer.

Comment: mutable! I should have known. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Another method without mutable (when that is not available) and const_cast is using pointer-members. The pointees don't follow the constness.

```
class FooMock : Foo
{
private: 
  boost::scoped_ptr<std::vector<int> > m_vector;
public:
  FooMock() : m_vector(new std::vector<int>) { }
  void sendEvent(int id) const {m_vector->push_back(id);}
}
```

When possible, I would use mutable for mocking.

Answer (score 1):

const-ness of a member-function is **a part** of the function signature. You cannot get rid of it.

However, you can define the member as `mutable`, which you want to *mutate* in a const member function. The keyword `mutable` would make the member mutable/modifiable even in a const-member function and even if the object is const.

Answer (score 0):

You could mark `m_vector` as `mutable`:

`mutable std::vector<int> m_vector;`

`mutable` generates a bit of controversy similar to `const_cast`, and it results in a bit of a theoretical discussion about what it *really* means to be `const`. Basically it would be justified here as long as the external behavior remains const-like, which I assume is true looking at this example.